# Django testing, assert CSV content is present

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests

I am doing a test to check the contents of a `csv` file using `assertContains()`:

```
response = client.get('/abc/1/a_b_csv')
print(response.content)
self.assertContains(response.content, 'aakash')
```

I tried different options such as `self.assertContains(response,'aakash')`
but didn't get any result.

My csv file looks like,

```
Name Age
Aakash 22
```

Sometimes there is the error:

```
bName\r\nVipul\r\n'
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_csv (timepay.new_test.ReportTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aakash/Projects/test.py", line 28, in test_csv
    self.assertNotContains(response.content, 'Vipul')
  File "/home/aakash/Projects/project_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 402, in assertNotContains
    response, text, status_code, msg_prefix, html)
  File "/home/vipul/Projects/project_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 355, in _assert_contains
    response.status_code, status_code,
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace of the error?

Comment: @Ralf updated the query

Comment: I added an answer for part of your problem. I need more info if you are still having problems (but see my answer for details)

Comment: Try using `request.json()` instead of `request.content`

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the stacktrace you added to the question, the stacktrace corresponds to the call to `self.assertNotContains(response.content, 'Vipul')`.

Looking at the docs for [`SimpleTestCase.assertNotContains()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertNotContains), I notice that the method expects the whole response, not just the content as parameter.

So, changing this line:

```
self.assertNotContains(response.content, 'Vipul')
```

to this

```
self.assertNotContains(response, 'Vipul')
```

should clear up the error for which you added the stacktrace.

---

Now, I notice that you also have this line in your question:

> I tried different options such as `self.assertContains(response,'aakash')`, but didn't get any result.

You will have to be more specific as to what you mean by `"didn't get any result"` if you want us to be able to help you.